# WPF - Button IsEnabled Binding Converter

Tags: wpf, button, binding, converters, isenabled

I have an `ObservableCollection<MyEntity>` and `MyEntity` has a `IsChecked` property with a `PropertyChanged` event.
I have a `Button` and I would like to change `IsEnabled` property to `true` when at least one of `MyEntity` of the `MyObservableCollection` is checked.
I created a converter which takes the `ObservableCollection` and return true when a `MyEntity` is checked at least.
But the `return "null"` is returned.
What is wrong ? Thank you for your help.

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyObservableCollection"/>
    <src:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, Source={StaticResource MyObservableCollection}}"/>
```

C# Converter

```
class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (null == value)
            return "null";

        ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object> items = (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>)value;

        List<MyEntity> myEntities = (from i in items select (MyEntity)i).ToList();

        foreach (MyEntity entity in myEntities)
        {
            if (entity.IsChecked)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding data into this collection `MyObservableCollection`?

Comment: Is the `value` object null? If so your source is just null, where do you actually populate your `CollectionViewSource` ?

Comment: The `CollectionViewSource` is populated in the `Window` `Constructor` and shown in a `DataGrid` which works well.

Comment: @Anthony: Try to populate it before InitializeComponent() call

Comment: @dwrd It is and the DataGrid is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Binding is wrong. The Converter want's the underlying collection not the `CollectionView`. And set the `CollectionViewSource.Source` after `InitializeComponent()`, the Binding will be refreshed.

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SourceCollection,
                            Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},
                            Source={StaticResource MyObservableCollection}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think Path=SourceCollection is the point that changes everything.

Answer (score 1):

Since StaticResources are resolved at the time of intializing itself i.e. at the time of `InitializeComponent()` but till that time your collection is yet not intialized that's why null value is passed to the converter.
So, better choice would be to move that property in your code behind and bind to that property since binding will be resloved after `InitializeComponent()`. Create property in your code-behind-

```
public CollectionViewSource MyObservableCollection { get; set; }
```

and bind to your button -

```
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding MyObservableCollection, RelativeSource=
{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```